# Query Data between to strings

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula, formula

So I am importing data from an external program, the problem is it imports the data not separated, so when I import and trans pose it, it ends up like this:

| Column A |
| --- |
| String#1 |
| Data 1 |
| Data 2 |
| Data 3 |
| String#2 |
| Data 4 |
| Data 5 |
| Data 6 |

I want to query the Data above so it grabs "string 1" and goes down until it gets to "String2", so I an rearrange the data to look like this:

| String 1 | String 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Data 1 | Data 5 |
| Data 2 | Data 6 |
| Data 3 | Data 7 |
| Data 4 | Data 8 |

---

I have absolutely no idea how todo this, my assumption is that the formula would look like this:

```
=QUERY(A:A, "Select A where A is between 'String 1' and 'String 2')
```

And no, I cannot change the way the data is imported from the external tool.
Any ideas and solutions would be very apricated

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Agreed. Formulas are written around specifics, not generalities. The most efficient and effective way to receive help that will easily translate to your real-world need is to share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it, or to a representative sample from it that is large enough to fully illustrate the goal and allow testing).

Comment: Is your data in between the strings numerical?

Comment: 1, I can't share the date due to it being under an NDA,
2, The reason for the generalities is because I want this to function dynamically, so the idea being that I can grab the data between two sort of headers in the data, most of the problem is just due to how it is imported in.
3, The way I am attempting to get it to function is with this formula here:

`=QUERY(CONCATENATE("E",MATCH(J16,E16:E,-1),":J",MATCH(I16,E16:E,1)),"Select E where E contains 'Wall'")`
The reason and Idea for the matches is that it gets the cell number associated with the big data string I have to grab from

Comment: I am then combining the matches with the row letter so it prints out E26:E, which I then hope can be used to replace the range in a query function, allowing the formula to be dynamic by simply grabbing the title of each section in this data string, so that it can be organized like this;

String 1  //   
Data      //  
String 2 //

The Match that is using string 1 and 2 to grab the cell number and concatenate with the Column letter is then searching one long column that is layed out like this

String 1
Data 
String 2
Data
String 3
Data

Etc..

Comment: Even if your spreadsheet is under NDA, you can still provide a link to a spreadsheet that realistically represents enough *sanitized data* to allow the volunteers here to have something to work with. No formula can be written around "String #1" and "String #2"; we need to know what those strings actually *are*, what kind of pattern they follow (or what kind of pattern the data points follow). The exception is if *every* block consists of exactly one header and three data points. If that is the case, please state that clearly in your post and here in comments.

Comment: Showing us a formula out of context isn't helpful and does not match your post details. Your formula references three columns that are involved (none of them "Column A"), whereas your post shows one linear column. There are just too many unknowns at this point. Set up a spreadsheet that closely mimics your actual sheet but replacing any confidential data with realistic dummy data—at least enough so that the problem/goal is fully represented. At least for me, that is the only way I can help you further.

Comment: @ErikTyler 
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nNbJevbXgHVIhOxjHXVLuknTrHaiiFmxb3ExyKrbCiM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sondre, I appreciate your sharing a link. But that spreadsheet does not contain *realistic* dummy data. I doubt that the entries in your real data all start with `Data` or that other values *all* begin with `Subset`, `Length`, etc. In addition, you have misspellings in that one example. Some of your sections don't have "Height" included. So, unfortunately, this leaves me no better off than before. Please share some *realistic* data (taken from your real sheet's CSV data and then changing any sensitive date by just a little bit), and show *exactly* the result you want from that example data.

Comment: @ErikTyler 
Unfortunately the dummy data is formatted exactly the same way, that is where my endless headache around this problem has stemmed from.

This misspelling is directly my fault on it, the data is driving me mad.

Comment: Sondre, I'm totally confused here. Your *actual* source data is made up of *just labels* — `Data 1:, Subset 1, Constraint 1, Length 1, Height 1, Data 1:, Subset 2, Constriant 2, Length 2, Height 2, Data 1: Subset 3`— with no actual data points? That doesn't make sense to me. I can only ask again: please share 1.) some *real, full lines of source data* and 2.) a *full* hand-entered example of what you want that *full* example data to look like after processing. I could write a formula around your one line of unrealistic dummy data, but it would not translate to your real sheet.

Comment: @ErikTyler
Here is an example of the data,

`Room #: 2, Wall #: 3, Length (in): 245, Height (in): 96, Dropdown: drywall, Doors: 1 door 30 X 80 inches , Windows: 0, Outlets/Switches/Phone/Internet Connections: 1 switch center left
2 outlets bottom center and right , Additional Wall Notes: 
Room #: 2, Wall #: 4, Length (in): 109, Height (in): 96, Dropdown: drywall, Doors: 0, Windows: 1 window 71 X 47 inches , Outlets/Switches/Phone/Internet Connections: 0, Additional Wall Notes:` 

^ all of that is contained in once cell.... I have tried every mixture of split with query and nothing works

Comment: Thus my eternal Headache.

Comment: Sondre, I understand you are under NDA (as I am with most of my paying clients). And I sense your frustration. We are a *little* closer, in that you've now shared *one* realistic data string (which, BTW, is *very different* from your generic one, as I suspected). But even under NDA, you can share a link to a spreadsheet containing, say, five actual source strings with any confidential data exchanged for realistic dummy data (e.g., "Fred Philips" to "John Doe," etc.) *along with your full desired output for those five lines of data*. As I said earlier, this is what I need if I'm to help you.

Comment: To keep hope alive here, suppose your string from three comments back is in A1 of some sheet. In some other range where two columns are empty, place the following formula: `=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(Room)","~$1"),"~",1,1)),", ",0)))`. If that is what you need, great, let me know and I'll post it as an official reply. If not, share a spreadsheet as described in my comment above.

Comment: Another layout option... Make sure for this one that you have *nine* empty columns and place this formula in the upper leftmost cell of that range: `=ArrayFormula({INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(Room)","~$1"),"~",1,1)),", ",0),":.+$",""),"(","\("),")","\)"),1);TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(Room)","~$1"),"~",1,1)),", ",0),JOIN(":|",INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(Room)","~$1"),"~",1,1)),", ",0),":.+$",""),"(","\("),")","\)"),1))&":",""))})`

Comment: @ErikTyler I have since been able to change the way the data was gathered in the first place, I did update the dummy data to have the most realistic data I could put in there, if you still want to take a peak at it for educational purposes. 
It is truly a one of a kind problem.

Comment: Educational purposes for whom? I don't understand.

Comment: Given your updated sheet, add another sheet (i.e., Sheet2) and place the following formula in cell A1 of that new sheet: `=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!B4,"(Room)","~$1"),",\s*([A-Z])","<$1"),"~",1,1)),"<",0)))`

Comment: Second layout, add Sheet3. In A1, use this: `=ArrayFormula({INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!B4,"(Room)","~$1"),",\s*([A-Z])","<$1"),"~",1,1)),"<",0),":.+$",""),"(","\("),")","\)"),1);TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!B4,"(Room)","~$1"),",\s*([A-Z])","<$1"),"~",1,1)),"<",0),JOIN(":|",INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!B4,"(Room)","~$1"),",\s*([A-Z])","<$1"),"~",1,1)),"<",0),":.+$",""),"(","\("),")","\)"),1))&":",""))})`

Comment: @ErikTyler What sort of makes this headache even worse for me, is that after two weeks of working on it, I found the guy who made the form collection come out this way, turns out a simple transpose(split(A1,Char(10))) does the trick.

Comment: Also @ErikTyler both of the array formulas work. Thank you!